# How to print out all the steps in Merge Sort?

Tags: c++, mergesort

I'm a 2nd year college student and we have this subject Data Structures and Algorithm and a newbie. My professor gives me task to code the merge sort algorithm but she lately added that it needs to display the partition (the image that I posted) in my code. This is the sample image that I want to have in my code after the "1st Partition". Thank you in advance I wish you all safe and sound!

[image]

and this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Merge two sub arrays L and M into collection'
    //(array, lower bound, mid bound, upper bound)
    //(array, 0, 3, 7)
void merge(int collection[], int p, int q, int r, int series) {

  // Create L <-- A[p..q] and M <-- A[q+1..r]
  //  n1 = 3 - 0 + 1
  //  n1 = 4
  int n1 = q - p + 1;
  //  n2 = 7 - 3
  //  n2 = 4
  int n2 = r - q;

  //  L[4],  M[4]
  int L[n1], M[n2];

//for (int i = 0; 0 < 4 ; i++)
  for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
//L[0,1,2,3] = collection[0,1,2,3] = [3,10,21,47]
    L[i] = collection[p + i];

//for (int j = 0; 0 < 4 ; j++)
  for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
//M[0,1,2,3] = collection[4,5,6,7] = [4,15,38,59]
    M[j] = collection[q + 1 + j];

  // Maintain current index of sub-arrays and main array
  int i, j, k;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = p;

  //If else statement to determine whether (ASCENDING) lowest to highest or (DESCENDING) highest to lowest
  if(series == 1){
      // Until we reach either end of either L or M, pick larger among
      // elements L and M and place them in the correct position at A[p..r]
      //    (0 < 4  && 0 < 4)
      while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
      //if ( 3   <=  4  )
        if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
        //collection[0] =  3
          collection[k] = L[i];
          i++;
        } else {
          collection[k] = M[j];
          j++;
        }
        k++;
      }
  }else{
      while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] >= M[j]) {
          collection[k] = L[i];
          i++;
        } else {
          collection[k] = M[j];
          j++;
        }
        k++;
      }
  }


  // When we run out of elements in either L or M,
  // pick up the remaining elements and put in A[p..r]
  while (i < n1) {
    collection[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

  while (j < n2) {
    collection[k] = M[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }
}


//------------------------MERGING-----------------------------
// Divide the array into two subarrays, sort them and merge them
            //(array, lower bound, upper bound)
            //(array, 0, 7)
void mergeSort(int collection[], int lb, int ub, int sequence) {
//if (lower bound < upper bound)
//if (0 < 7)
  if (lb < ub) {
    // m is the point where the array is divided into two subarrays
    // m = 0 + (7 -0) / 2
    // m = 0 + 7 / 2
    // m = 3
    int mid = lb + (ub - lb) / 2;

    //Call mergeSort
    //mergeSort(collection, 0, 3)
    mergeSort(collection, lb, mid, sequence);
    //mergeSort(collection, 3 + 1, 7)
    mergeSort(collection, mid + 1, ub, sequence);

    // Merge the sorted subarrays
    //merge(collection, 0, 3, 7)
    merge(collection, lb, mid, ub, sequence);
  }
}

//----------------OUTPUT---------------------
// Print the array
void printArray(int collection[], int scale) {
  for (int i = 0; i < scale; i++)
    cout << collection[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}


//---------------MAIN PROGRAM----------------
// Driver program
int main() {
  int array_size;
  int order;

  cout << "Instructions. Enter array size with a minimum of 4 and maximum of 16" << endl;
  cout << "Enter array size: ";
  cin >> array_size;
  cout << endl;

  if (array_size <=3 || array_size >= 17){
    cout << "Your array size is maybe below or above the array size limits. Please try again" << endl;
    exit(0);
  }

  cout << "In what order do you want to sort your numbers? Press [1] ASCENDING, [2] DESCENDING" << endl;
  cout << "Enter: ";
  cin >> order;
  cout << endl;

int collection[array_size];
  cout << "Enter " << array_size << " numbers: ";

  for (int u = 0; u < array_size; u++){
    cin >> collection[u];
  }

  int scale = sizeof(collection) / sizeof(collection[0]);

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Before Sorting: \n";
  printArray(collection, scale);

  mergeSort(collection, 0, scale - 1, order);

  cout << "1st Partition:";
  //RIGHT HERE

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Sorted Array: \n";
  printArray(collection, scale);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just print using ```cout``` inside ```merge```, what's the problem?

Comment: If you really want to have it in main "after 1st partition", you need to store it somewhere. However, the easiest way is to print it with each call to mergeSort and merge

Comment: Pass arrays using std::array it will avoid a lot of headache.

Comment: @frozenca Hello! Thank you for answering my question. I just didn't know where to put it and everytime I add `cout` in the `merge` it wont run.

Comment: @frozenca Hello! Can you help me with my code? I still can't figure it out. Thank you very much!